# Retrieve The bar difference value of a condition

Tags: pine-script

I have a script that Identifies a pivotlow. If a candlestick close is less than the pivotlow,I want to be able to retrieve the highest candlestick in the range of the pivotlow and the candlestick that closed below the pivotlow.

I have tried using ta.barssince(pivotlow) and then passed the value retrieved from the ta.barssince(pivotlow) and used it as the length for ta.highest(high, length) but i keep getting "error, length must be greater than zero".

Please can you help me with the code ?

Comment: With the information you provided, it’s difficult to answer your question. 
Could you please share your code and if possible, some screen captures so that we can better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough to say with the information provided, but my guess is you want to find the highest value between a pivot low and a bar that closes below that value. This is how I did it with a for loop.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

type pivotLow
    float p
    int b 

var line line1 = na
var newH = 0.0
var plArr = array.new<pivotLow>()

pl = ta.pivotlow(5,5)
bars = ta.barssince(not na(pl))

if not na(pl) 
    plArr.unshift(pivotLow.new(low[5], bar_index[5]))
    newH := 0.0

if plArr.size() > 0 
    if close < plArr.get(0).p
        (line1[1]).delete()
        for i = 0 to bars+4
            if high[i] > newH
                newH := high[i]
        line1 := line.new(plArr.get(0).b, newH, bar_index, newH)
```

[image: chart]